# Why the Minimum matching is wrong?

Tags: php, regex

```
<?php
    $str='00160.Day';
    $pattern = "/(.+?)('.Day')/i";
    $replacement = "\${1}";
    print preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
?>
```

Why the output is `00160.Day` ,not `00160`?What is the matter with my Minimum matching  regular expression?

Comment: `('.Day')` <- See the single quotes in there? If you delete them both, you get 200pt. + your code will work, **who would have thought that?!**

Comment: May be you want to use explode or preg_split function rather than regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single Quote `'` around day is cause of unexpected output. `.` should also be escaped. Use below pattern.

```
"/(.+?)(\.Day)/i";
```

Comment: *WHY*, should OP use this pattern, what is different? Why did you changed it?